# If $(x_n+y_n)$ converges, then either $(x_n)$ or $(y_n)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am not sure how to approach proving this since it is not apparent to me that it is true. Wouldn't both sequence need to be convergent for the sum to be convergent? I tried to prove from contraposition that if $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are both divergent then their sum would be as well, but I am stuck.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is not true.

Consider the sequences:

1. $a_n = (-1)^n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$
2. $b_n = (-1)^{n+1}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Then $a_n+b_n=0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so these sequences' sums converge, but none of them converge individually.

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly false,  as we can let $x_n=n, y_n=-n$, so that both sequences diverge.  But $x_n+y_n=0$, a constant sequence.

Same goes for the respective series'.

Answer (score 0):

The limiting difference of the harmonic series and the natural logarithm converges to the euler-mascheroni constant although both sequences are divergent.